# How to remove duplicate dic from array and order dic by some key?

Tags: python

My list like below:

```
[
  {code:"code1",name:"name1",position:"p1"},
  {code:"code2",name:"name2",position:"p2"},
  ......
]
```

But there is some duplicate `code` in the list. My question is how to remove the duplicate code from  list. I can do it by build `for` loop and traversal the list again and again, but I think probably there is some straightforward methods can do this in python.
I also need sorted the array by key `code`, how can I do it without write loop by myself?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a list of dictionaries with keys as a variable that are not defined. It throws an error:

> NameError: name 'code' is not defined

If I change them to the type `string` by enclosing the keys in quotes, I get the following:

```py
[
    {"code": "code1", "name": "name1", "position": "p1"},
    {"code": "code2", "name": "name2", "position": "p2"}.
    ......
]
```

Let the above list be `some_list`. To remove duplicates from the list of dictionaries:

```py
some_list = [dict(t) for t in {tuple(d.items()) for d in some_list}]
```

To sort the list of dicts by the key `code`:

```py
some_list = sorted(some_list, key=lambda k: k['code'])
```